# memory allocation change

Tags: java

```
public void changeColor(int[] value) 
{
    color = value;
}
```

In the above code Color is a is a int Array in a class. and value is a array in the scope of method ChangeColor. By Color = value; I am assigning the memory space allocated to value to Color. As per my understanding once a method ended the variable specific to the method will be deleted, in that case will Color be able to access its value after the method ends??

Comment: in idiomatic Java classes are named in `UpperCamelCase` and variables are `lowerCamelCase`. Your example is potentially confusing because of this non-standard naming you are using. Also `Color` is a `Class` in the JDK, which confuses the issue even more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"will Color be able to access its value after the method ends??"
Short answer: Yes, otherwise why would you define a variable as global.(No matter it's a reference or primitive)

Please run this code to see what happens:

```
public class Test {
    int[] Color = new int[2];
    int i = 20;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.ChangeColor(new int[] {1,2,3});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t.Color));
        System.out.print(t.i);

    }
    public  void ChangeColor(int[] value) 
    {
        Color = value;
        i = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `int[] value` parameter of the method is a reference to an array, but not a copy of the full array. Color is also a reference, so when you assign them, you make them point to the same array.

when the method exists, value is deleted from memory, but that was just a reference, not the array. So color which is still pointing to the array, will still be able to access even if the method has finished.